# Can Deactivate guard runs only once in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

Yes I know it is a `duplicate issue` but previous post does not solve it.
**Guard code:**

```
  canDeactivate(component: ExamEndedComponent,
                currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, currentState: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.store.select(fromRoot.getExamStatus)
      .pipe(
        take(1),
        map((res: string) => {
          console.log(res);
          if (res === 'started') {
            alert('stop');
           console.log(currentState.url);
            return false;
          }
          return true;
        })
      );
  }
```

but the problem is when clicking on `back button` of browser the guard executes only once so when `clicking again` user can actually navigate away .
**Also checked the issue in angular** : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12851
but it tries to solve the issue by navigating again to the current route before return false like below :

```
 canDeactivate(component: ExamEndedComponent,
                currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, currentState: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.store.select(fromRoot.getExamStatus)
      .pipe(
        take(1),
        map((res: string) => {
          console.log(res);
          if (res === 'started') {
            alert('Deactivation blocked');
           console.log(currentState.url);
            this.router.navigate([currentState.url]);
            return false;
          }
          return true;
        })
      );
  }
```

At this point alert is called twice because before returning false I navigate to currentState so angular runs candeactivate again but after clicking again at back button the canDeactivate is not called.
 Routing table :

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'Authentication', component: AuthComponent},
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, children: [
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'exam', pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: 'exam', component: ExamComponent, children: [
          {path: '', redirectTo: 'start', pathMatch: 'full'},
          {path: 'start', component: ExamStartComponent},
          {path: 'started', component: ExamQuestionsComponent,
            canActivate: [ExamQuestionsGuard],
            canDeactivate: [ExamStartedDeactivateGuard]},
          {path: 'ended', component: ExamEndedComponent, canDeactivate: [ExamStartedDeactivateGuard]}
        ], resolve: {exam:  ExamResolver}}
    ],
    canActivate: [AuthGuard], resolve: {sign: SignInResolver}}
];
```

What is the problem ? Thanks in advance .

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having a similar issue...

Comment: @Chuck. Yes it because canDeactivate is not intended for use with browser navigation. It can only guard when we manually navigate between angular routes (such as router.navigate or router-link). I was using canDeactivate to protect router but solved it by using canActivate guard.

Comment: Thanks for the info. canActivate will guard against browser navigation?

Comment: yes it will . Otherwise no reason to use guards)